# Square Root Time Complexity

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, recursion, analysis-of-algorithms

I'm deeply sorry for this, I don't know if it's the appropriate place to post this but I just can't figure out what's the time complexity of this algorithm:

```
int fun(int n)
{
    int j = 10;
    while( j < n)
        j+= sqrt(j);
    return j;
}
```

I know that at the $k^{th}$ iteration we have $f(k)=f(k-1)+\sqrt{f(k-1)}$, with $f(0)=10$, I tried solving this function, but I couldn't find any way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the second derivative of the function is a constant value, so you can approximate it with a quadratic function.

The values for $a$ and $b$ in the quadratic function take on values of around $0.00001$, so $$f(n) \approx 0.00001n^2+0.00001n+10$$

Comment: How did you do that? That is show that the second derivative is a constant!

Comment: to proof it exactly takes some work, but just by calculating the values and looking at the second derivative, you can see it.

Comment: Thank you, I have found the second derivative but how can I plug in values for example f'(k+1) is dependent on f'(k) and so on for f''(k+1).

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But if you use your recursive expression and then you take the difference between $f(k)$ for every $k$ (this is $f'(k)$ )and then again you take the difference (so the second derivative) between $f'(k)$ for every $k$, you will see it.

Comment: What do u mean, something like $f(k+1)-f(k)$ , then $f(k+2)-f(k+1)$,... and so on?
If so, I got $f(k+n)-f(k)=\sqrt{f(k)}+\sqrt{f(k+1)}+...+\sqrt{f(k+n-1)}$, I didn't clearly see where there's a derivative.

Comment: no, the second derivative so $ (f(k+2)-f(k+1))- (f(k+1)-f(k))$. I checked it numerically, not analytically.

Comment: It is not true that the second difference is identically zero.  It is $1$ when the step after function value crosses a square.

Comment: @RossMillikan   who said it was zero? It is a constant value I said. That's what led to looking for a quadratic function that is in the answer.

Comment: It is not constant.  It oscillates between 0 and 1.  I find it is 1 at 3,6,8,10

Comment: In my simulation, it converges to 0.5 and stays constant...

Comment: The variables are integers, so the combination you posted 10 hours ago is also an integer.  It can average $0.5$, which makes some sense.  Note that OP has confirmed we are interested in the number of iterations, not in the function value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the time complexity or the value of the function?  You add at least $3$ every cycle.  The number of loops is then less than or equal to $\frac 13(n-10)+1$ so the time complexity is $O(n)$

Comment: I'm trying to find the complexity and its not $O(n)$ it is $O(\sqrt{n})$, but I still don't know how to prove it